# Windows DDK 4.0 not building some obj files

Tags: windows, driver, device, wdk

The sources in the source file are lance.c send.c  request.c  alloc.c    Pcntn3.rc

Builds only:  send.obj   request.obj    alloc.obj    Pcntn3.res

error LNK1181: cannot open input file "obj\i386\lance.obj"

expecting it to build lance.obj so the compiler can do the final linking for the sys file.

Not on the hard drive anywhere.

Comment: Compile lance.c?

Comment: Yes lance.c is what AMD names their routine file.